# Webpage is not displayed in iPod from IIS

Tags: iis, ipod-touch

I have created one application, that is hosted in IIS. When i am displaying IIS webpage in iPod it displays error message like below,

> Cannot Open Page Safari could not open the page bacause the server
>   stopped responding..

any one know the reason for this error message?

**Note: default.html page is opening. Getting error when only giving "http://ipaddress/mypage.html"**

Comment: What do your IIS server logs say? I assume this is over Wi-Fi, can any other devices access your website via your wireless network?

Comment: I am able to connect iis site from my pc

Comment: Is the IIS instance on the same PC that you're accessing it from? Does the request from the IPod actually show up in the IIS logs for the site?